# Extract a row in html file without the html tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract a row containing a specific string but my following code gives html tags along with it.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import codecs
import sys


get_company = "ABB LTD"


OUTFILE = os.path.join('company', 'a', 'viewids')

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/company/a/searches/a"))
rows = soup.findAll("table",{"id":"cos"})[0].findAll('tr')
userrows = [t for t in rows if t.findAll(text=re.compile(get_company))]
print userrows
```

This is my table format

```
<table id="cos" width="500" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>CIK Number</th>
    <th>SIC Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>A CONSULTING TEAM INC</td>
    <td align="right">1040792</td>
    <td align="right">7380</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>A J&amp;J PHARMA CORP</td>
    <td align="right">1140452</td>
    <td align="right">9995</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if I need A J&J PHARMA CORP's CIK number how to do it? Right now it gives me an output like this:

```
[<tr valign="top">
    <td>A J&amp;J PHARMA CORP</td>
    <td align="right">1140452</td>
    <td align="right">9995</td>
  </tr>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html= '''
<table id="cos" width="500" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>CIK Number</th>
    <th>SIC Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>A CONSULTING TEAM INC</td>
    <td align="right">1040792</td>
    <td align="right">7380</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>A J&amp;J PHARMA CORP</td>
    <td align="right">1140452</td>
    <td align="right">9995</td>
  </tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"id":"cos"})
td = table.find('td', text='A J&amp;J PHARMA CORP')
# ^ This return text node, not td.
print(td.parent.parent.findAll('td')[1].string)
```

prints

```
1140452
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. 
Is it possible if I could search for A J&J PHARMA CORP rather than A J&amp; J PHARMA CORP?

Comment: @user3092632, Yes, it is possible using [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape): `td = table.find('td', text=cgi.escape('A J&J PHARMA CORP'))`

Comment: @user3092632, If you use bs4, you don't need to escape yourself.